# Get part of an array and keep key value

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to get a part of an array but when I do the key does not carry over with it.

for instance if I have:

```
Array
(
    [default_route] => Array
        (
            [path] => /
            [controller] => IndexController
            [action] => indexAction
        )

    [hello_route] => Array
        (
            [path] => /hello
            [controller] => HelloController
            [action] => helloAction
        )
)
```

and I would like to get just the array with the index of `default_route` it returns that array but the key is removed so the result is:

```
Array <- no more key string...
(
    [path] => /
    [controller] => IndexController
    [action] => indexAction
)
```

I tried `array_intersect_key($routes, array_flip(array($key)));` but that places a single array into another array which is pointless because there will never be more than one at a time. I don't want a 2 dimensional array with one element in it, I would like just the array with the correct key value.

implementation:

```
    foreach ($routes as $key => $val)
    {
        // $routeArray = array_intersect_key($routes, array_flip(array($key)));
        // would put whats above but that is what creates the unnecessary two  dimensional array 
        $routeObj = new Route($routes[$key]);

        $newRouteObjs[] = $routeObj;
    }

    return $newRouteObjs;
```

and here is the constructor for the route. I was just going to take the array and break it apart.

```
public function __construct(array $route)
{
    $this->name = key($route);
    $this->path = $route['path'];
    $this->controller = $route['controller'];
    $this->action = $route['action'];
}
```

I simply want to pull out the section and keep the key string. I have a feeling this is easy and I am just missing something.

Comment: Can we see the code so we can see the implementation? I can only assume this is in a `foreach($array as $val)` and you're just lacking `foreach($array as $key => $val)`

Comment: Do u want only default route array ?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy there is the implementation

Comment: Can we see the constructor function of `Route` and other relevant snippets that will affect how `newRouteObjs` is created please

Comment: @Ohgodwhy there is the constructor the reason I need the key to keep its value is because I use it for the name of the route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you simple add a new parameter to your constructor for the name?

```
class Route
{
    public function __construct(array $route, $name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->path = $route['path'];
        $this->controller = $route['controller'];
        $this->action = $route['action'];
    }
}
```

Then you can call it as:

```
$routeObj = new Route($routes[$key], $key);
```

And it should give you the desired result as:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Route Object
        (
            [name] => default_route
            [path] => /
            [controller] => IndexController
            [action] => indexAction
        )

    [1] => Route Object
        (
            [name] => hello_route
            [path] => /hello
            [controller] => HelloController
            [action] => helloAction
        )

)
```

---

And one way you could use to bypass the limitation of losing the key would be to re-assign it within your `foreach`:

```
foreach ($routes as $key => $val)
{
    // $routeArray = array_intersect_key($routes, array_flip(array($key)));
    // would put whats above but that is what creates the unnecessary two  dimensional array 
    $routes[$key]['name'] = $key;
    $routeObj = new Route($routes[$key]);

    $newRouteObjs[] = $routeObj;
}
```

And the class:

```
class Route
{
    public function __construct(array $route)
    {
        $this->name = $route['name'];
        $this->path = $route['path'];
        $this->controller = $route['controller'];
        $this->action = $route['action'];
    }
}
```

Comment: that gives me what I needed. I would have liked to find some way not to have to add the second param. I figured there had to be a way to do so. It seems like something that would be common. Anyways, Thank you!

Comment: @zachstarnes the thing is the moment you fetch the current item and pass it up the key reference is gone as it is tied to the first array only and not the inner one.

Comment: @zachstarnes you can however bypass that, see my update at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is just how you construct `$newRouteObjs` because you're passing in `[]` which is an unindexed array. Simply index it:

```
foreach ($routes as $key => $val)
{ 
    $routeObj = new Route($routes[$key]);

    //add [$key] as opposed to []
    $newRouteObjs[$key] = $routeObj;
}

return $newRouteObjs;
```

And this is the dump:

```
Array
(
    [default_route] => Route Object
    (
        [name] => path
        [path] => /
        [controller] => IndexController
        [action] => indexAction
    )

    [hello_route] => Route Object
    (
        [name] => path
        [path] => /hello
        [controller] => HelloController
        [action] => helloAction
    )

)
```

[And here's a working example](http://ideone.com/fork/IcdoU1)

Comment: unfortunately that is not correct because the name is not the key like it is supposed to be. The name in your example is `path` when it is supposed to be the key of the array. i.e. `default_route` or `hello_route`

Comment: @zachstarnes Ah, I see what you're saying, let me resolve that for you